# Randomly coloring provinces in country map?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, color, colormap

I have created a map of a country in QGIS.

1. How do I color the province individually ?
2. Is there a quick way to randomly coloring all the province of a country.

I am using the "ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces" shapefile from Natural Earth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Layer Styling (right-click - Properties - Symbology, or Layer Styling Panel)
2. Select "Categorized"
3. Pick a Value field (Province in your case?)
4. Color ramp "Random colors"
5. Click "Classify":

[image]

If you want to change colors, click the individual colors and adjust.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful, I managed to do it1

Comment: @LeMoaiVoyageur nice. If it solved your problem please accept my answer with the checkbox

Comment: With pleasure  @BERA I have rated your reply using the arrow, and the tick is green. is this what you meant ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at 'Topological coloring' which is in the Processing Toolbox. This will create a new field called 'color_id' in the attribute table of the polygon layer that can be used for styling in such a way that adjacent polygons never have the same colour, while using a limited number of colours.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, This is a different way from the one described above by @bera . However how to you create that new filed "color_id" ? Is there a tutorial that could help with that process ? Many thanks again, S